# Change CSS class based on existence

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly I must emphasis that the HTML is pre-generated and cannot be altered - Otherwise I would not be doing it in this way : )

So....

The script and HTML below creates a nice hide/show menu, when you click the navheader the navitem becomes visible.

However I want the css class of the navheader to change based on if navitem is directly below it.

e.g.

```
navheader (Change Class to linksbelow)
  navitem
navheader (Change Class to NOlinksbelow)
navheader (Change Class to NOlinksbelow)
navheader (Change Class to linksbelow)
  navitem
etc....
```

My HTML and JQUERY:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            $('.Nav table .navitem').hide();
                $('.Nav table.navheader').click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().parent().next().find(".navitem").slideToggle('100');
                });
            });
</script>

<div class="Nav">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="navheader">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a class="navheader" href="#">Header Link 1</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="navitem">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="navitem" href="#">Link 1</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="navheader">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a class="navheader" href="#">Header link 2</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this specific case doesn't seem to work out when using only CSS selectors (as there's no such thing as a 'previous sibling selector'), so it'll have to be a little more complex:

```
$('.Nav tr:has(table.navheader)').each(function (i, elmnt) { 
    if($(elmnt).next().find('table.navitem').length > 0) 
        $(elmnt).find('table.navheader').addClass('linksbelow')
});
```

Comment: Its complicated but it works, however it applies the class to the TR not the navheader.

Any pointers?

Comment: Oh yeah, 'scuse me, forgot about that... give me a minute, I'll try to work it out.

Comment: I think you could just do $(...).parent().addClass('link...');